# How i send email without authentication using java

Tags: java, email, authentication, smtp

I would like to send email without authentication using java.
Can someone help me?

With authentication, I do it as follows:

```
    public void sendEmail() throws EmailException{
    SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.addTo("XXX@gmail.com", "XXXX");
    email.setFrom("XXXX@gmail.com","XXXXX");
    email.setSubject("testando . . .");
    email.setMsg("testando 1");
    email.setSSL(true);
    email.setAuthentication("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "XXXXX");
    email.send();
}
```

I forgot to say that i do not have a provider. i need an provider finally, i have emailFrom Subject and Message, and need send this email how?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.  You can send email without authenticating only if the mail server allows it, in which case you would omit the `setAuthentication()` call.  If the SMTP server requires authentication you must provide it.  If you are testing you can use a mock SMTP server, or set up your own real SMTP server and configure it without authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is only for testing purposes, you may try [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/). While it’s running, Papercut automatically picks up e-mail sent to the standard SMTP port (25) on any IP address. You just send mail from your application and switch to Papercut to review it.

Papercut @ github: 
https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut/releases

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "127.0.0.1");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@test.com"));
        message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("a@b.com"));
        message.setSubject("Notification");
        message.setText("Successful!", "UTF-8"); // as "text/plain"
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        Transport.send(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I want to use sendgrid apikey ,how I should send it ?

Comment: The Github link is still working, but the website link to Papercut is down.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class SimpleEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("SimpleEmail Start");
        String smtpHostServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String toEmail = "XXXX@gmail.com";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHostServer);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
            msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("n91eply@gmail.com", "NoReply-JD"));
            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("n91eply@gmail.com", false));
            msg.setSubject("SimpleEmail Testing Subject", "UTF-8");
            msg.setText("SimpleEmail Testing Body", "UTF-8");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
            System.out.println("Message is ready");
            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Facing An Issue
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError o6sm1435614pgg.37 - gsmtp

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2249)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1740)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1239)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
 at com.necti.smsemail.SimpleEmail.main(SimpleEmail.java:59)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
// File Name SendEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Via: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

Comment: I forgot to say that i do not have a provider.
i need an provider 

finally, i have emailFrom Subject and Message, and need send this email

how?

Comment: You saw the link at the end of the answer?
I do not quite understand your doubts here in comment?